# How to update automaticaly(refresh) QlineEdit connected to mysql database in pyqt?

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I have a Dialog box (PyQt designer) contains 4 QlineEdit each one connected to database(mysql),my problem is how to display their content without updating each time the value change in the database(I use python as a programming language)??

Comment: You should consider using QSqlDatabase and do all modifications through its model interface (a [QSqlQueryModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html) or [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html)), then you can use a [QDataWidgetMapper](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html) to automatically synchronize fields.

Comment: I will try,Thanks.